# dplyr n_distinct with condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Using dplyr to summarise a dataset, I want to call n_distinct to count the number of unique occurrences in a column. However, I also want to do another summarise() for all unique occurrences in a column where a condition in another column is satisfied.

Example dataframe named "a":

```
A B
1 Y
2 N
3 Y
1 Y
```

`a %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(A))`

However I also want to add a count of `n_distinct(A)` where `B == "Y"`

The result should be:

```
count
    3
```

when you add the condition the result should be:

```
count
    2
```

The end result I am trying to achieve is both statements merged into one call that gives me a result like

```
count_all  count_BisY
        3           2
```

What is the appropriate way to go about this with dplyr?

Comment: Can you try using: a %>% summaries(count = n_distinct(A[B == 'Y']))?

Comment: @user3949008 Error: Input to n_distinct() must be a single variable name from the data set

Comment: Sorry, this works n_distinct(df$A[df$B == 'Y']).

Comment: I still get the same error :S! `a %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(a$A[a$B == 'Y']))`

Comment: I mean by itself - not pipe the df, works.

Comment: It seems to me that what @Gopala proposes is the correct answer. In particular `data.frame(A = c(1:3,1), B = c('Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y')) %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(A[B == 'Y']), count_all = n_distinct(A))` works for me (with dplyr 0.7.6).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An alternative is to use the `uniqueN` function from *data.table* inside *dplyr*:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
a %>% summarise(count_all = n_distinct(A), count_BisY = uniqueN(A[B == 'Y']))
```

which gives:

```
  count_all count_BisY
1         3          2
```

---

You can also do everything with *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[, .(count_all = uniqueN(A), count_BisY = uniqueN(A[B == 'Y']))]
```

which gives the same result.

Answer (score 16):

This produces the distinct A counts by each value of B using dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
  group_by(B) %>%
  summarise(count = n_distinct(A))
```

This produces the result:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

       B count
  (fctr) (int)
1      N     1
2      Y     2
```

To produce the desired output added above using dplyr, you can do the following:

```
a %>% summarise(count_all = n_distinct(A), count_BisY = length(unique(A[B == 'Y'])))
```

This produces the result:

```
  count_all count_BisY
1         3          2
```

Answer (score 3):

Filtering the dataframe before performing the summarise works

```
a %>%
  filter(B=="Y") %>%
  summarise(count = n_distinct(A))
```

Comment: I understand that, apologies for being unclear, my end goal is to have a result where it shows the count of total, and the count where B=="Y" in one table. I could do each separately and cbind them together I suppose

Comment: Can you replace filter() with group_by(B)? Does that get you what you want?

Comment: Yeah actually I think that works, it just adds an extra column and extra rows where I can really have it consolidated to have a column representing the number of `B == 'Y'`. I realize this isn't tidy data but it is what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
 aggregate(cbind(count=A)~B, a, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))
 #  B count
 #1 N 1
 #2 Y 2
```

Based on the OP's expected output

```
 data.frame(count=length(unique(a$A)), 
            count_BisY = length(unique(a$A[a$B=="Y"])))
```

Comment: Yeah for sure, aggregate is pretty intuitive for me but I have been trying to learn the dplyr language because it benchmarks faster speeds and accepts more than just dataframes

Comment: @RyanCastner Thanks for the feedback.   But, in some situations I find it useful to have `base R` solutions.  For example, recently, I had to implement a group by operation in Alteryx, but the version available have some problems in using dplyr.  So, have to resort to base R.